# Detect when the main thread is locked/busy (IOS)

Tags: ios, nsthread

Is there any way to detect when the main thread is locked/busy (aka will not respond to touch events) ?

possible directions
check the size of the dispatch_get_main_queue (but i dont know how to manipulate this object to see its size)

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isIgnoringInteractionEvents]
 but this method only works part of the time

Comment: Can you give us more context? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You might want to do this to improve application responsiveness. I am also trying to find a way to detect calls that are blocking main thread for more then X seconds. Of course you can use Time Profiler but it does not show you the absolute time ui thread (main thread) was blocked.

Comment: You can try to print the ID number of the running thread and then get some intuition which thread currently runs.

Answer (score 4):

Use instruments tool "time profiler" and then find the clue about what's blocking your main thread.

For example:
I find a method is running 12.7% cpu time of main thread.
Then I find it has name "waitingThread". It looks like the method is blocking the main thread.

[image]